# How to make a macro that dynamically prints an integer in hex with leading zeros

Tags: macros, rust, println

I am looking to create a macro that will display a type of number in hex along leading zeros equal to its size. For example, `hex!(2u8)` will print `$02` (leading zero) and `hex!(2u16)` will print `$0002` (16bit leading zeros)

This is what I have now, but it only works for 8bit numbers. It will display numbers larger than 8bit, but it won't display leading zeros equal to the size. I need a way to substitute the size of the integer in for `2` in `${:02X}` but the `print!()` macro requires a string literal.

```
macro_rules! hex {
    ($val:expr) => {{
        println!("${:02X}", $val);
    }}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of directly printing it somewhere I suggest using a wrapper structure which will format the content according to your needs:

```
use std::fmt;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct UpperHexLeadingZeroes<T>(pub T);
impl<T: fmt::UpperHex> fmt::Display for UpperHexLeadingZeroes<T> {
    fn fmt(&self, w: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        use std::mem::size_of;
        let width = size_of::<T>() * 2; // 2 nibbles per byte
        write!(w, "${:0width$X}", self.0, width = width)
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
fn main() {
    println!("{}", UpperHexLeadingZeroes(2u8));
    println!("{}", UpperHexLeadingZeroes(2u16));
    println!("{}", UpperHexLeadingZeroes(2u32));
    println!("{}", UpperHexLeadingZeroes(2u64));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't really need a macro for this. With the [Formatter's dollar syntax](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fmt/index.html#width), the width of the printed value can be specified in terms of an expression, as you intend here.

```
fn hex<T: UpperHex>(e: T) {
    println!("{:01$X}", e, mem::align_of::<T>() * 2);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=b1e29d65ffca3d6f61e86a1bac782e56&version=stable)